# Is it possible to use GridView without a MaterialApp in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and i'm struggling with some concepts.

I'm unable to use the GridView() widget inside a container like this :

```dart
class _ProductsGridState extends State<ProductsGrid> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The debug console give me this error :

> package:flutter/src/painting/basic_types.dart': Failed assertion: line 225 pos 10: 'textDirection != null': is not true

Thank you ! :)

Comment: Why you don't want to use ``MaterialApp``. Try setting ``direction: Axis.vertical`` to the grid view constructor and it should work.

Comment: @OMiShah Am I forced to use MaterialApp ? I don't really want the AppBar and everything else :/

Comment: If you don't need the app bar then you can simply ignore the ``appBar`` property by not setting it in the ``Scaffold`` and you will notice that there is no app bar. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MaterialApp is the **root level** widget of your app it does a lot of work behind the scenes to give you a basic page in which you add multiple widgets that flutter render to display on screen.Without Materialapp, your app not works correctly.